# Problem with FormulaLookup and FormulaData

Tags: function-construction, probability-or-statistics, curated-data

I'm not getting an answer when I type either:

```
FormulaLookup["BinomialDistribution"]
```

or

```
FormulaData["BinomialDistribution"]
```

Can't be my fault because I get the correct answer when I type:

```
FormulaData["BoseEinsteinDistribution"]
```

Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: `BinomialDistribution` is a built-in. Use `PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], x]`

Comment: I am knowing that. I am wanting the formula for the binomial as implemented in Mathematica. Thanks anyway for your time.